# Need to intersect multiple images on show / hide upon checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, show-hide

I am new to Javascript / Jquery, so please bear with me as I try to explain the issue I'm running into.

https://jsfiddle.net/ciemo/tnogzw0t/

BASIC SETUP: 
- **#middle div** - contains a menu with 4 categories (Artist, Tools, Location, and Style). Each category has multiple checkboxes underneath.
- **#right div** - contains an image gallery of thumbnails that have a grayscale filter at 50% opacity set up in css.

GOAL:
When user selects one of the checkboxes of **any** category, the corresponding images will show/hide based on the selection of checkboxes. On show, the images change to filter none at 100% opacity.

I can get each checkbox to show / hide images upon selection on an independent basis, but I would like to find a method to only show images that share the same class as the checked selections. For example, if you choose an artistName1 and a Location1, only images shared between those two selections should appear, but right now ALL images of artistName1 and ALL images of Location1 show. After reading through different forums, I'm looking for a way to intersect these.

Javascript:
    $(document).ready(function() {
      "use strict";

```
  //begin Artist Name 1
  $('#Broderick').val($(this).is(':checked'));

  $('#Broderick').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('.Brod').css({
            filter: 'none',
            opacity: '1'
          });
          $('.Brod').parent().next().css({
            opacity: '.8'
          });
        } else {
          $('.Brod').removeAttr('style');
          $('.Brod').parent().next().removeAttr('style');
        }

        //begin Artist Name 2 
        $('#Kenny').val($(this).is(':checked'));

        $('#Kenny').change(function() {
              if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.Kenn').css({
                  filter: 'none',
                  opacity: '1'
                });
                $('.Kenn').parent().next().css({
                  opacity: '.8'
                });
              } else {
                $('.Kenn').removeAttr('style');
                $('.Kenn').parent().next().removeAttr('style');
              }

              //begin Location 1
              $('#Northeast').val($(this).is(':checked'));

              $('#Northeast').change(function() {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                      $('.NE').css({
                        filter: 'none',
                        opacity: '1'
                      });
                      $('.NE').parent().next().css({
                        opacity: '.8'
                      });
                    } else {
                      $('.NE').removeAttr('style');
                      $('.NE').parent().next().removeAttr('style');
                    }

               //begin Location 2
                    $('#Southeast').val($(this).is(':checked'));

                    $('#Southeast').change(function() {
                      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        $('.SE').css({
                          filter: 'none',
                          opacity: '1'
                        });
                        $('.SE').parent().next().css({
                          opacity: '.8'
                        });
                      } else {
                        $('.SE').removeAttr('style');
                        $('.SE').parent().next().removeAttr('style');
                      }

                    });
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle of your issue? helps alot.

Comment: you talk about elements that doesn't exist in the snippet, please add more code.

Comment: Man ... I've started the code... but it does not met the BOTH requirement... maybe this could give you an starting point.

https://jsfiddle.net/b6Le0d3g/1/

Comment: Thank you, this is a great starting point!! I am able to implement and the code you set up works...as you mentioned, I'm still looking for a way that satisfies the BOTH requirement. In the mean time, in the code you provided how do I make my captions hide when the selection is unchecked? I tried to put in an else statement, but the captions remain.